# Power Apps capture users initials from Displayed Name to add to unique ID

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I'm wanting to create a Power App unique ID that adds an Office 365 profile displayed name that's in SharePoint list. This profile displayed name may or may not be the user submitting the request. The Unique ID would look like this: ORG-0005-IN.

The 1st part is the Change Request type, the 2nd would be the SharePoint ID, 3rd first & last initial.

Comment: So, what help exactly you need, only to get the initials from currently logged in user name or to construct the complete unique ID?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Split and Concat functions to extract the initials from the user's full name. If the user’s name is "John Doe", the initials would be "JD".

`Concat(Split(User().FullName, " "), Left(Result, 1))`

Combine these initials with other components to form the unique ID. For example, if the Change Request type is "ORG", the SharePoint ID is "0005", and the initials are "JD", the unique ID would be "ORG-0005-JD".

`"ORG-" & SharePointID & "-" & Concat(Split(User().FullName, " "), Left(Result, 1))`

Let me know if this helps.

Ref:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-get-users-initals-into-a-label/td-p/44939

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Unique-ID-based-on-initials-of-their-name/td-p/1199635